# import ibm_db_sa Fails with: AttributeError: type object 'String' has no attribute 'RETURNS_CONDITIONAL'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, sqlalchemy

OS: Win 10 22H2

Python: 3.9.13

Install location: C:\Program Files\Python39

ibm-db
Version: 3.1.4

ibm-db-sa
Version: 0.3.9

SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.7

When running python -i and import ibm_db_sa I get the below.  Any help appreciated. I searched for dependencies but did not find anything useful.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> python -i
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ibm_db
>>> import ibm_db_sa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_sa\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import ibm_db, pyodbc, base
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_sa\ibm_db.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .base import DB2ExecutionContext, DB2Dialect
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_sa\base.py", line 662, in <module>
    class DB2Dialect(default.DefaultDialect):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_sa\base.py", line 675, in DB2Dialect
    returns_unicode_strings = sa_types.String.RETURNS_CONDITIONAL
AttributeError: type object 'String' has no attribute 'RETURNS_CONDITIONAL'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue and discovered the solution after a contact at IBM gave me a lead.

It looks like the ibm_db_sa package was just updated earlier in the month. If you look at the prerequisites on the product description page you will see it requires "*SQLAlchemy version between 0.7.3 - 1.4.x*". The latest version of SQLAlchemy is 2.0, which you have installed like I did.

I uninstalled SQLAlchemy, and reinstalled a down-leveled version.

- pip3 uninstall sqlalchemy
- pip3 install sqlalchemy==1.4.47

Once I did this, I was able to run the import cleanly.

Update:
I did discover backleveling SQLAlchemy caused a dependency issue with ipython-sql. and had to run the additional commands.

- pip3 uninstall ipython-sql
- pip3 install ipython-sql==0.4.1

Comment: Sweet!  Did what you suggested (pip3 install sqlalchemy==1.4.47) and that resolve my issue.  Thanks!